# Is the org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates extension point meant to be used for code templates?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've created a new project wizard and it creates a blank file. I want the file to contain some sample code. I don't want to put the sample code there via a static String. Should I be looking to add the [org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors_templates.html&cp=2_1_1_148) extension point to my plug-in project or is this not its intended purpose? Based on what I've read, it sounds like it's perhaps only intended for code completion templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the JavaDoc for the `org.eclipse.jface.text.templates` package that provides this support says:

> Templates are shortcuts for frequently used fragments of text such as
>   code patterns or complex text entities. They may contain variables
>   which are only resolved at the time when the template is inserted
>   within a context. Together with linked mode, inserting a template can
>   create a on-the-fly edit mask within a text viewer.
>
> Templates are specified as text, variables are defined using the
>   ${variable} notation known from Ant, for example.

So I think they can be used to insert any text.